# Gitlab fails on "gem" installtion

Tags: shell, ubuntu, rubygems, gitlab

I've installed this:

```
# Install curl and sudo
apt-get install curl sudo

# 3 steps in 1 command :)
curl https://raw.github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-recipes/master/install/debian_ubuntu.sh | sh
```

[Tutorial here...](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/installation.md#4-install-gitlab-and-configuration-check-status-configuration)

But when I try step 4

```
sudo gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.8'
```

I've got this error - can someone please help me?

```
$ sudo gem install charlock_holmes --version '0.6.8'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
$
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found an solution, it was quite simple ...

I had to install libyaml and reinstall ruby.

Just have a look at this [site](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/10/31/install-ruby-193-with-libyaml-on-centos/)